# LDAP Filter: Return entries within multiple OUs

Tags: ldap, ou

Assume a tree looking like this

```
ROOT
    OU=ABC
        OU=Users and Groups
            OU=Users
                CN=USER1
                CN=USER2
                CN=GRP1
    OU=DFG
        OU=Users and Groups
            OU=Users
                CN=USER3
                CN=USER4
                CN=GRP2
```

I want to retrieve USER1-4 from this tree.

I have tried this:

```
ou:dn:=Users
```

and (which seems not to be allowed):

```
distinguishedName=*Users*
```

The former only returns the two "Users" containers not the users contained within them:

```
OU=Users,OU=Users and Groups,OU=ABC,ROOT
OU=Users,OU=Users and Groups,OU=DFG,ROOT
```

How do I retrieve the users?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The filter '(ou:dn:=Users)' will work with all LDAPv3 compliant servers, but is unfortunately not supported with Active Directory.
You cannot achieve this in a single request when the server is AD!